# Ubuntu Linux Cannot Connect to Internet(Ethernet)

Tags: networking, internet

I have Linux and Windows in a dual boot setup. I will occasionally use Linux but I mostly use Windows. (I know nothing about Linux command lines) I am on desktop running Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS, 64-bit, GNOME Version - 3.36.3. Today when I tried to use Linux there was no internet connection. I went to check settings under the network tab but the only things that show are a VPN not set up and Network Proxy settings. I tried looking this up but everything that I come across requires terminal commands that are either not Ubuntu/Ubuntu-related commands or are things that I need to download of which I cannot without connection.

Edit: I won't be able to reply to anything for the next few hours. (I believe 2-3) I have to go do some things in the meantime.

Edit2: I am back.

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo   -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: We currently don't know what Ubuntu you're asking about?  Is it server? desktop? specialist release?  The network tab implies desktop, but you haven't actually told us any of that basic detail yet.  What OS & release are you uasking about?

Comment: Not sure if you can mention/reply but I am on desktop running Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS, 64-bit, GNOME Version - 3.36.3. I hope this is helpful.
Edit: caught me just in time! I have few minutes before I need to go though.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by future readers. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our uplink to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: Hi there waltinator! I already had done that. At first it skipped my mind but I went and did it after I commented. Sorry about that!